# XmlSerializer works on Firefox but .xml does not work on IE JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, string, internet-explorer, firefox

I create a node(or xml object I am not sure) on client side and I try to save that xml file locally. My goal is convert xml node(or object) to string and save in a text file.

Problem is following method converts xml to string on Firefox but does not convert on IE

so I have a root xml object:

```
console.log(xmlToString(root));
//save_content_to_file(xmlToString(root), "C:\\test");

}

function xmlToString(xmlData) { 

    var xmlString;
    //IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else{
        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    }
    return xmlString;
}
```

output on FF:

```
<plist><dict><key>subject</key><string></string><key>date</key><string></string><key>time</key><string></string><key>briefings</key><array><dict><key>files</key><array><dict><key>date</key><string>2012/09/09</string><key>name</key><string></string><key>description</key><string></string></dict></array><key>subject</key><string></string><key>presenter</key><string></string><key>time</key><string></string></dict></array></dict></plist>
```

output on IE:
`undefined object`

EDIT:::

Added following method nothing has changed

```
function serializeXmlDoc(xmlDoc) {
    if (window.XMLSerializer) {
        return (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
    } else if (typeof xmlDoc.xml != "undefined") {
        return xmlDoc.xml;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Any idea how can I fix this on IE?

Comment: The `XMLSerializer` might not be supported by your IE version yet, so you might want to start looking for a third party library that provide similar functionality as `XMLSerializer`.

Comment: @Jay IE version is 9 I guess it is the latest version